# Expanding DataGrid column crash on visual.cs

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid

On a simple WPF project, .NET 7, I can reproduce an issue on my datagrid that I cannot explain.

On my empty **DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter** I can easily expand column.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="RowsDataGrid1" ItemsSource="{Binding DataView}" CanUserSortColumns="{Binding HasAtLeastOneRow}">
                <DataGrid.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <Grid Grid.Row="0" Background="DarkBlue" Margin="0,0,0,5">
                                <Border BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                    <DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter />
                                </Border>
                                <Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="0,1,1,1" Margin="0,0,1,0"/>
                            </Grid>

                            <ScrollViewer Height="350" x:Name="dataGridScroller" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{Binding HasAtLeastOneRow, Converter={StaticResource gBoolToVisibilityConverter}}" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{Binding HasAtLeastOneRow, Converter={StaticResource gBoolToVisibilityConverter}}">
                                <Border BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" BorderBrush="Gray">
                                    <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" />
                                </Border>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </DataGrid.Template>
            </DataGrid>
```

The DataView object is the `DataTable?.DefaultView`.
I have 1 button to add 100 hundred line (element get from `DataView.AddNew()` and defined)
And 1 button to erase all datagrid rows through a loop with `DataView.Delete(i);`

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
    public bool HasAtLeastOneRow => DataView?.Count > 0;

    public DataTable DataTable
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public DataView DataView => DataTable.DefaultView;

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        DataTable = new DataTable();
        DataTable.Columns.Add("Column1", typeof(string));
        DataTable.Columns.Add("Column2", typeof(string));
        DataTable.Columns.Add("Column3", typeof(string));

        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(DataView)));
    }

    public RelayCommand AddOneThousandElementCommand => new RelayCommand(
        () =>
        {
            for (int indexer = 0; indexer < 1001; indexer++)
            {
                var element = DataView.AddNew();
                element.Row[0] = $"element{DataView.Count + indexer}, A";
                element.Row[1] = $"element{DataView.Count + indexer}, B";
                element.Row[2] = $"element{DataView.Count + indexer}, C";
            }
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(HasAtLeastOneRow)));
        });

    public RelayCommand AddOneHundredElementCommand => new RelayCommand(
        () =>
        {
            for (int indexer = 0; indexer < 101; indexer++)
            {
                var element = DataView.AddNew();
                element.Row[0] = $"element{DataView.Count + indexer}, A";
                element.Row[1] = $"element{DataView.Count + indexer}, B";
                element.Row[2] = $"element{DataView.Count + indexer}, C";
            }
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(HasAtLeastOneRow)));
        });

    public RelayCommand EraseAllElementCommand => new RelayCommand(
        () =>
        {
            while (DataView.Count > 0)
            {
                DataView.Delete(0);
            }
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(HasAtLeastOneRow)));
        });
}
```

Finally, I raise PropertyChanged of `HasAtLeastOneRow` property to refresh visibility statement.

**The problem :** But after this moment, when I try to expand a column size, there is a crash on visual.cs :

```
The specified Visual is not an ancestor of this Visual
```

I found other thread which are talking about directly programmaticaly instruction on DataGrid and explains that the visual tree isn't already built. Example :
[Exception: The specified Visual is not an ancestor of this Visual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041714/exception-the-specified-visual-is-not-an-ancestor-of-this-visual)

But it's not my situation : I don't manipulate programmaticaly the DataGrid..

This crash appaear other strange behavior on the DataGrid :

- if I'm trying to Scroll bottom which forces the horizontal scrollbar visibility to "Visible" and I try to erase all, it crash immediately).
- if I'm trying to sort the column after a total erasement, same thing.
- if I define ScrollViewer Visibility to "Hidden" it crashed at launch !

Is there something to do after a total erasement which need to be done before other manipulations ? Or something I don't get about DataGrid behavior ?

UPDATE 2024 january 15 : I Opened an Issue ticket on dotnet/WPF github repository. It is actually "investigated" : https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/8640

Comment: Please provide sufficient markup and code to allow a minimal reproduction of your issue.

Comment: I added code from VM @Andy ; the last code part are now fore RelayCommand and Converter. I Can add it if it's necessary.

Comment: I created an issue on dotnet/wpf repository in order to find a solution :
https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/8640. By the way, a part of this issue (same exception is happens at mass deletion) seems to be solved in .NET 8.