# The specified Visual is not a descendant of this Visual Exception

Tags: wpf

I am getting The **"specified Visual is not a descendant of this Visual"** exception.

Can you please help on what scenarios we will get this exception as stacktrace is not helping me to identify the issue?

Stack-trace:

> at System.Windows.Media.Visual.TrySimpleTransformToAncestor(Visual
>   ancestor, Boolean inverse, GeneralTransform& generalTransform, Matrix&
>   simpleTransform)    at
>   System.Windows.Media.Visual.InternalTransformToAncestor(Visual
>   ancestor, Boolean inverse)    at
>   System.Windows.Window.HandleWmNcHitTestMsg(IntPtr lParam, IntPtr&
>   refInt)    at System.Windows.Window.WindowFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd,
>   Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)    at
>   System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.PublicHooksFilterMessage(IntPtr
>   hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)    at
>   MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam,
>   IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)    at
>   MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate
>   callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)    at
>   MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object
>   source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate
>   catchHandler)

Comment: Are you using convertor in your Xaml?

Comment: Did you look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/2837293/512365. BTW - can  you show some code or explain what your code is trying to do?